# I have web.config file. I want to apply the url rules I made to subfolders as well. The code only working in the root directory

Tags: asp.net, xml, .htaccess, web-config

I have 3 subfolders under root directory

/Root

--en-US

--fr-FR

--ar-AR

```
<rewrite>
       <rules>        
          <rule name="rule 1q" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^sayfa-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)"  />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/menu-detay.php?sef={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
         <rule name="rule 2q" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^urun-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/urun.php?sef={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
          <rule name="rule 3q" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^page-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/en-US/menu-detay.php?sef={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="rule 4q" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^product-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/en-US/urun.php?sef={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="rule 5q" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^page-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/fr-FR/menu-detay.php?sef={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="rule 6q" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^product-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)"  />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/fr-FR/urun.php?sef={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="rule 7q" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^page-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)"  />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/ar-AR/menu-detay.php?sef={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="rule 8q" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^product-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)"  />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/ar-AR/urun.php?sef={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
         </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

only rule 1q and rule 2q only work in root directory (subfolders Not Found
The requested document was not found on this server.) If I put the web configuration file in a subfolder, this time the other rules work, but rule 1q and rule 2q in the root directory do not. I hope I was able to explain. thanks